# Can't unsubscribe observable in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am currently trying to test some method of a component in Jasmine, which looks like this :

```
  putInTrashcan(cat: Catalogue): void {

    const put = this.catalogueService
      .putInTrashcan({ id: cat.id })
      .subscribe(res => {
        put.unsubscribe();
        this.catalogues.splice(this.catalogues.indexOf(cat), 1);
      });
  }
```

When the function is called with a given object, the service inside places that object in the trash and then after confirmation, the object is removed from the list. The service is just some HTTP request.

I've had some issues testing it, at first because it wouldn't go in the subscription and the object was never deleted from the array, but after declaring it as fakeAsync and flushing it, that part seems to work (I'm not 100% sure why this was necessary as previous tests that seemed to have fundamentally the same behavior worked without it). The current test is written as :

```
  it('Delete catalogue', fakeAsync( () => {
    cats = [cat1];
    serviceMock.getCatalogues.and.returnValue(of(cats));
    serviceMock.putInTrashcan.and.returnValue(of(cat1));
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.putInTrashcan(cat1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();

    expect(component.catalogues.length).toBe(0);
  }));
```

The array of objects is defined, put as a return for the initialization (this part seems to work from all other tests), and its only element is set to be deleted. This seems to all work except for one thing : the unsubscription does not work. Running the test gives me the error

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'put' before initialization
```

If I comment out that line, the test does function, but I can't really leave that line out. Removing the flush just leaves me with

```
Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.
```

I'm not quite sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `take(1)` to close the Observable instead of unsubscribing.

```
putInTrashcan(cat: Catalogue): void {

  this.catalogueService
    .putInTrashcan({ id: cat.id })
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.catalogues.splice(this.catalogues.indexOf(cat), 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: It does seem to work, I will ask if I can modify the original code, since I am only doing the unit testing.